# How to generate/retrieve file in datalake using message queue?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure function `QueueTrigger1` that executes a function `executeTemplateProcess` to upload a tsv file on Google Drive and update a Jira ticket.

I need to create a Message Queue to generate a tsv file on datalake, run a python code, and then retrieve the tsv file (location) from the datalake and add it to the queue.

I have a basic foundation for the queue today, but i am not sure how to generate the file on the datalake and retrieve its location. We need to pass the file into the python code as input, thats why I am thinking we would need the file location on the datalake to be enqueued, but I am not sure how to perform this.

This is the namespaces for both the `QueueTrigger1` and the `executeTemplateProcess()`

```
namespace DI
{
    public class DIProcess
    {
        public static void executeTemplateProcess(string jiraKey, string jiraIssueType, string jiraSummary, Component component, string jiraDescription)
        {
            if (rowCount > 0)
            {   //python code would run somewhere here following queue process before jira code executes below
                string dfileId = CopyTemplate(component.FileId, sheetName);

                // stop process if copy template not sucessfull
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dfileId))
                    return;

                jira.AddComment("Google File copied.");

                // Update JIRA with the web link
                webLink = $"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{dfileId}";
                jira.AddWebLink(webLink, sheetName);
                jira.AddComment("Jira weblink added.");
            }
            else
            {
                jira.UpdateStatus("Abandoned");
                jira.AddComment("Jira status updated to Abandoned.");
            }
        }
    }
}   

namespace companyxyzjira.QueueTrigger1
{
    public static class JiraQueueTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("QueueTrigger1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("companyxyz-jira-dev-am", Connection = "storageaccountcompanyxyzji42f6_STORAGE")]string myQueueItem
            , ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            dynamic jira;
            string jiraKey;
            string jiraIssueType;
            string jiraSummary;
            string jiraDescription;
            string[] jiraComponentNames;
            Component jiraComponent;

            log.LogInformation("Queue trigger function processing");

            jira = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myQueueItem);

            jiraKey = jira.issue.key;
            jiraIssueType = jira.issue.fields.issuetype.name;
            jiraSummary = jira.issue.fields.summary;
            jiraDescription = jira.issue.fields.description;

            try
            {
                DIProcess.executeTemplateProcess(jiraKey, jiraIssueType, jiraSummary, jiraComponent, jiraDescription);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                log.LogError(e.ToString());
                log.LogError(e.Message);
                log.LogError(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose this is my line of thinking but I am not sure how to communicate with the datalake...

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req, [Queue("companyxyz-jira-dev-pm-mapping-done")] ICollector<string> QueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];
    
    string requestBody = String.Empty;
    using (StreamReader streamReader =  new  StreamReader(req.Body))
    {
        requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        QueueItem.Add(requestBody); //i think?
    }
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    
    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"{name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

datalake snapshot with input/output files (uploaded manually but thats what we want to automate from now on so we need to generate/retrieve these artifacts from/to message queue as described above)

[image: datalake]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
import pandas as pd

connect_str = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')
    
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
#Put above code out of the body of function.

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("test")
file_client = directory_client.create_file("uploaded-file0316.txt")

#Upload to datalake
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
l = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (l , columns = head)
data = df.to_csv(index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")
output = data.replace(',', '\t')
print(output)
file_client.append_data(data=output, offset=0, length=len(output))
file_client.flush_data(len(output))

#download from datalake
download = file_client.download_file()
content = download.readall()
print(content)
```

Comment: Thanks Bowman! So you think this should run directly from the python code instead? The reason I was considering message queue is because we wanted a sort of ”file watcher” to trigger the rest of the `executeTemplateProcess()`, so is this python code acting like this, eliminating need for queue? Also, what if we need to retrieve the location of a blob (e.g. tsv) file AFTER the executeTemplateProcess does the work, how to pass the location of the file from Azure data lake?

Comment: @Cataster You mean you need to get the location of the generated file and save it to the queue? If so, I think metadata should have path information

Comment: The code in my answer describes how to interact with datalake using sdk(generate files and get information about existing files)

Comment: Do you need Python or C# to do this?

Comment: I suppose at first I was going for c# because we want to integrate a sort of filewatcher (e.g. message queue?) that watches for files uploaded after the jira process kicks in.

Comment: I think I probably understand what you want, so you are just unfamiliar with datalake file processing?

Comment: Sorry, it's time for me to sleep. If there is any response, please leave a message here.:) And you can try to search the azure sdk api reference, that will be really helpful.:)

Comment: yes im unfamiliar with datalake processing. I checked out resource here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp-script . I basically need a message queue to act as filewatcher when file is in datalake, i.e. `input.tsv` and pass that to python code argument that my colleague usually runs in Jupyter manually, then the python code will perform some ML calculations and output an `output.tsv` file. This is being done manually every morning by her, and she has to store the files on her computer and later upload them to drive

Comment: btw, when running your python code sample, i am getting this errors: `map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)` `azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (FilesystemNotFound) The specified filesystem does not exist.`

Comment: @Cataster You need to first create a container named `test`. I did not write if-else to check whether the filesystem is been created because I think that makes the code look too much. In the answer, I listed the most important code, of course, you can also create a filesystem like this by code: service_client.createfilesystemxxx, but you need if-else to make sure the second time you run it can go to the logic of service_client.get_file_system_client, otherwise it will throw error.

Comment: oh so whats the diffrence between those 2 lines? `file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("test")` i am thinking the first line creates the container test and the second line fetches it? but if thats correct, then i dont have a test container. why would it complain then since its just creating one from scratch?

Comment: @Cataster Datalake is a hierarchical structure. So if you want to put files in a folder, you need to specify the folder name. The file-system-client corresponds to the container, and the directory-client corresponds to the folder in the container.

Comment: @Cataster No, the first is fetch the container, the second is fetch the directory.

Comment: Awesome it worked now! sry this was giving me some troubles since i never programmed in python haha. I think we still need a message queue, so maybe ADSL2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp-script may be the better approach for a message queue. We need a message queue i suppose to act as file watcher. I think you acknowledged yesterday what we're trying to do. how do i build on top of the c# code to perform datalake operations using messageququq per my pseudocode?

Comment: @Cataster I saw the link you posted, it is the blob binding of azure function. If you use it to generate files, there will be a problem. Your colleague can't process the files generated by blobservice using the datalake package.

Comment: oh how come? but we just need the file/blob location and pass that into message queue and from there pass that as argument to python code, wouldnt that work?

Comment: What do you use to generate these files? Just need to ensure that they are generated based on datalake sdk.

Comment: They are generated using Jira. but my colleague has to navigate to the Jira and download the file, parse it so that she only keeps the first 7 columns (there are like 50 columns that are not required), pass it as input into her TEMPLATE.ipynb and runs the code in jupyter which then generates a mappings.tsv output file, and then she opens that mappings.tsv file and copies a column that basically is recommendations calculated by the python code she ran and pastes it back into the input.tsv file she had used earlier.

Comment: then she uploads the modified file back into the datalake, and i think from the datalake we'd also want to take that file once its detected and upload to google drive. also, i think the sdk is no longer required in Azure Data Lake v2. Apparently we can use the Blob Input Binding directly with ADLSv2 thanks to multi-protocol access.

Comment: @Cataster Sorry, I am a little fainted . Some of the services you mentioned I never used before(like Jira). Can you simply restate what you need?

Comment: haha np. So basically we are trying to automate a manual process today. my colleague developed a python machine learning code that calculates recommendations for certain products based on an input.tsv file. she only uses 4 columns out of the 50 columns there are in this tsv file. so to make it easier on her she parses this big input.tsv file and only keeps like 7 columns. I know i mentioned she uses 4, so then you may wonder then why does she keep 7? well the other 3 columns are "recommendation" columns. they are initially empty. Thats what her machine learning code is used for

Comment: The machine learning code is used to generate recommendations from 4 columns. once the notebook (python code) finishes running, it generates a file called mappings.tsv. this mappings.tsv contains one of the 3 recommendation columns today. she is still working on the other 2 recommendation fields from the 3 other columns i mentioned, but basically thats the whole gist with the python code. so she has to download the input.tsv file from a Jira task onto her local computer every morning, pass it as input to the notebook, and once the notebook runs it geenrates that mappings.tsv file which she

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230009/discussion-between-bowman-zhu-and-cataster).

Comment: then opens the mappings.tsv file, copies the values generated in the "recommendation" column, and pastes these values into the input.tsv file in one of those 3 out of the 7 columns i mentioned earlier. she also uploads it to the datalake. As you can see this is highly manual and we want to automate it all. but for now we need to consider creating a sort of file watcher for the datalake, and one way (simplest we can think of) we're thinking is message queue.